# INSERT gives Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x80' for column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.7

I am facing issues with my table structure :

#### My_Table_Name1

```
CREATE TABLE `My_Table_Name1` (
  `twitter_id_str` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_screen_name` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `twitter_id_str` (`twitter_id_str`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

For database I also have same charset and collation:

`CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

I'm trying to insert an emoji into this table:

```
insert into My_Table_Name1 values("2","")
```

However, I get an error:

> Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x80' for column 'twitter_screen_name' at row 1 0.00027 sec

How to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When are you facing issues? While creating the table?  Or when entering data? Please provide more details in your question by [editing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/206478/edit) it.

Comment: at the time of data insertion, i am trying to enter an emoji.     17:44:18 insert into My_Table_Name1 values("2","") Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x80' for column 'twitter_screen_name' at row 1 0.00027 sec

Comment: Just tried this on MySQL 5.7 - The smiley gets converted to "\U+1F600" as I paste it into the mysql client, and running the insert then just works.

Comment: @RAJKASHWAN Maybe the problem is with mysql-workbench? It seems to work fine with the command-line client, but haven't tested with mysql-workbench. Are you using the most recent version?

Comment: I am using mysql5.7

Answer (score 6):

The problem appears to be in the Client.

When the client connects to the MySQL server, it needs to announce that the bytes in the client are `utf8mb4`.  This can be done in several ways:

- In the connection parameters (client-dependent).
- `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.

`\U+1F600` is the Unicode representation for that Emoji.
`\xF0\x9F\x98\x80` is the equivalent Hex.
`F09F9880` is the UTF-8 (utf8mb4) in Hex.

Avoid the Unicode representation.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a problem with mysql-workbench (tested with version 6.3.9 on Fedora and MySQL 5.7 (CentOS)) where emojis are not converted to the correct unicode.

In the command-line `mysql` client the emojis get converted to codes when they're pasted in, so the query

```
INSERT INTO My_Table_Name1 values("2","");
```

becomes:

```
INSERT INTO My_Table_Name1 values("4","\U+1F600");
```

which works fine.

However, in mysql-workbench, the emoji is not converted as you paste it in, and the query result is:

> Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x80' for column 'twitter_screen_name' at row 1